# Changing Style of Buttons, knobs, etc. in Visual C++

Tags: image, visual-c++, button, coding-style, replace

I am very new to Visual c++ and am still trying to learn some very basic things. I am trying to change the default pictures for knobs, buttons, etc. and replace them with my own pictures. How Can I accomplish this? (I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to learn how to "ownerdraw" your controls (buttons, ... ); or if you go the easier way, you can use bitmaps in CButton (CBitmapButton) but it might not be enough for you.

This MSDN technical note is a good start : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk2h3c6w%28VS.71%29.aspx